# XML and DTD: The content of element type must match

Tags: xml, dtd, dtd-parsing

I'm learning XML at the moment and I'm struggling with the first DTD extension.

My DTD  :

```
<!ELEMENT  biblio (livre*) >

<!ELEMENT  livre (achat , auteurs, titre ) >
<!ATTLIST livre langue CDATA  #IMPLIED
         ref  CDATA  #IMPLIED>



<!ELEMENT  achat EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST achat  date CDATA #IMPLIED
        lieu CDATA #IMPLIED>


<!ELEMENT  titre (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST titre genre CDATA #IMPLIED
        type NMTOKEN #IMPLIED>



<!ELEMENT  auteurs (auteur+) >


<!ELEMENT  auteur ( nom?, prenom? ,sexe?) >
<!ELEMENT nom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT prenom (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sexe (#PCDATA)>
```

If I launched the parser,it seems :

> The content of element type "livre"  must match (achat , auteus ,titre )

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE biblio SYSTEM  "Dtdbiblio.dtd">



<biblio>
    <livre langue="francais" ref="1684561564">
        <achat date="11/11/1993" lieu="london"/>
        <titre genre="G" type="politique">      Tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitre </titre>
        <auteurs>
            <auteur>
                <nom>x</nom>
                <prenom>x</prenom>
                <sexe>H</sexe>
            </auteur>
        </auteurs>
    </livre>

</biblio>
```

How resolve this problem?

Comment: addd me please :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commas (`,`) in `(achat , auteurs, titre )` specify the order that the elements must appear. ([See here for more detail.](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-element-content))

So `(achat , auteurs, titre )` means exactly one `achat` followed by exactly one `auteurs` followed by exaclty one `titre`.

You just need to change the order of `titre` and `auteurs`... either in the XML instance:

```
<biblio>
    <livre langue="francais" ref="1684561564">
        <achat date="11/11/1993" lieu="london"/>
        <auteurs>
            <auteur>
                <nom>x</nom>
                <prenom>x</prenom>
                <sexe>H</sexe>
            </auteur>
        </auteurs>
        <titre genre="G" type="politique">      Tiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiitre </titre>
    </livre>

</biblio>
```

or in the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT  livre (achat, titre, auteurs) >
```